# EOL conversion in bash

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing

Let's say that i have a file that was created with Unix EOL format.
Now, before sending that file to a windows, EOL conversion must be done.

I need to do this in bash and this is what i have so far:

For simplicity, let's say that my file is called file_linux.txt and it gives the following outputs:

```
cat -A file_linux.txt
first line$
second line$
third line$

file file_linux.txt
file_linux.txt: ASCII text
```

So it seems that only thing i need to do is to add carriage return (^M or \r) right before the **$** symbol.

My idea was to use sed to replace every **$** with **\r$** the following way:

```
sed 's/$/\r$/g' file_linux.txt | cat -A
first line^M$$
second line^M$$
third line^M$$
```

As you can see, i piped the output of sed to a cat -A. I expected **$** to be replaced with **\r$** but it seems that i have an extra **$** at the end.

Also, if i pipe this sed to a plain cat i get this strange result:

```
sed 's/$/\r$/g' file_linux.txt | cat 
$irst line
$econd line
$hird line
```

When i pipe it to a file, it seems like it is not a windows file:

```
sed 's/$/\r$/g' file_linux.txt | file -
file_linux.txt: ASCII text, with CR, LF line terminators
```

because when i do this to a file that was imported from a windows system i get the following output:

```
file_from_win.txt: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
```

Also, i was experimenting with this and it turns out that removing the second **$** in sed solves the problem:

```
sed 's/$/\r/g' file_linux.txt | file -
file_linux.txt: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators

sed 's/$/\r/g' file_linux.txt | cat -A
first line^M$
second line^M$
third line^M$
```

I am wondering why this last thing works, shouldn't characters between first and second slash in sed be
replaced with characters between second and third slash? I mean, if it were like that, in this last example i'd have a file that has **\r** in place where **$** previously was, which is not the case. It seems as if **\r** was simply added right before **$**.

I did this on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$` that you are matching on the LHS of the command is not a character - it's a regular expression meta-character *representing* the end-of-line (sometimes referred to as a line [anchor](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refanchors.html) - one of a larger class of [zero-length assertions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)).

In a sed substitution command `s/pattern/replacement/` only the LHS `pattern` is interpreted as a regular expression. Characters like `^` and `$` which represent  anchors on the LHS are plain literal characters in the RHS `replacement` text. In fact, everything on the RHS is literal with the exception of the following possible *backreferences*:

> The replacement can contain \n (n being a number from 1 to 9, inclusive) references, which refer to the portion of the match which is contained between the nth \( and its matching \). Also, the replacement can contain unescaped & characters which reference the whole matched portion of the pattern space.

FYI although `sed 's/$/\r/` and `sed 's/\r$//` are perfectly good ways of converting line-endings from UNIX to DOS and from DOS to UNIX (you don't need the `g` modifier BTW - by definition a line can have only a single ending), there are also dedicated utilities `unix2dos` and `dos2unix` available from the `dos2unix` package in Ubuntu's `universe` repository. As well as line-endings, these will handle things like the files' encoding and byte order mark (BOM).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So basically, whenever i have ```$``` on the LHS of sed, it's going to put whatever i have on the RHS right before the end of the line, and that's why i had  ```\r$$``` at the end of every line in the first case. If that's so, then why \r$ is only visible when i add -A switch to cat command? Also, why do i have ```$``` at the beginning of every line instead of first character in that case when piping to plain cat? Is ```\r$``` now interpreted as EOL or what?

Comment: @cdummie when you use `s/$/\r$/`, lines in the *file* end in `\r$\n` (carriage return - literal $ - line feed). The *terminal* writes out (for example) `first line`, then processes the carriage return, writes `$` (**over**writing the first character, `f`), and then processes the line feed.